# what does the 6 represent in this line of code (var rValue = data[i][6];)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out why the (6) in the below code will only look at column 7 in my spreadsheet. i have tried changing the number - no luck. thanks in advance

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        var rValue = data[i][6];

        if (rValue == salesPerson1) {
            Cat1.push(data[i]);
        } else if (rValue == salesPerson2) {
            Cat2.push(data[i]);
        } else if (rValue == salesPerson3) {
            Cat3.push(data[i]);
         } else if (rValue == salesPerson4) {
            Cat4.push(data[i]);
        } else { //Fail Safe
            Cat1.push(data[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: it represents the 7th element of `data[i]`, which should be an array for it to work / not crash. In other words, `data` should be an array of arrays. Arrays are zero-numbered (the first element is element number 0) so the 7th element is number 6.

Comment: technically, `data[i]` could be a string (not likely in this case)